# Properties of coefficients of cohomology theories

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

Coefficients of cohomology theories can come from a variety of categories: fields, rings, sheaves ...

I wonder: what are the properties an object must satisfy in order to be a legitimate candidate for coefficients of a cohomology theory? What is the most general such object or structure in some suitable sense?

Comment: This is a very vague question: cohomology theories on *what*? If the answer is "topological spaces", or possibly "topoi", the most general thing you can take the cohomology of is a sheaf of spectra, but of course you can have (co)homology of many other weirder objects

Comment: According to Grothendieck your categories of coefficients should always satisfy a six functors formalism. But I agree that it's not really a well posed question.

Comment: @DanPetersen Well, then I want a precise definition of a six functors formalism :) (I know one for the category of schemes, of course, but if we are being ridiculously general...).